# Convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} n!f(n^{-n})$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Let f be a positive function and the second derivative of f exists for all x. We are given that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)>0$. Prove convergence of $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} n!f(n^{-n})$$

So I have showed that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} n!\cdot n^{-n}$ converges and I figured the sum we are asked to prove converges because our function is increasing around $0$ (so decreasing when we approach $0$ from the right) so we can find a $K \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for $n \geq K$ then $n!f(n^{-n})\leq n!\cdot n^{-n}$ and therefor convergent (is it true that such a $K$ exists? - if so is there a good argument or proof of this?).

I'm also not sure why we are given the existense of the second derivative, is it a necessary condition? And if it is a necesarry condition is there a good counterexample then?

I also figured this would be true in general, so if we for example were to look at $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} f\left(\frac{1}{n^{1.01}}\right)$$ would that also be convergent?

Comment: hint: $f(x)/x$ is bounded for $x$ around $0$, because it has a limit at $x=0$

Comment: @BK It is not true that such a $K$ exists. However, it is true that for any $c > f'(0)$, there exists a $K \in \Bbb N$ such that for $n \geq K$, $n!f(n^{-n}) \leq \color{red}{c} \cdot n! \cdot n^{-n}$. The existence of the second derivative ensures that $f'(x)$ is continuous, which is indeed important.

Comment: Oh that makes sense thank you @Ben

Answer (score 1):

We don't need the second derivative to exist. We don't even need $f'(0)$ to exist. All we need is the existence of $C>0$ and $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)|\le C|x|$ for $|x|<\delta.$ If we have that (and we certainly do when $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)$ exists), then note that for $n>1/\delta$ we have $n^n>1/\delta,$ hence $1/n^n<\delta.$ For such $n$ we then have

$$\tag 1 n!|f(1/n^n)|\le n!(C/n^n) = C(n!/n^n).$$

Since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n!n^{-n}<\infty,$ the series
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n!|f(1/n^n)|<\infty$ by $(1),$ hence $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n!f(1/n^n)$ converges.

And yes, with the same hypotheses, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(1/n^{1.01})$ converges absolutely.

Comment: Typo in equation (1). Otherwise, nice answer!

Comment: @Nicolas   Thanks, edited.